# Adding Filter to Existing Replication

Tags: sql-server

I did set up replication some months before and there is 200GB worth of data containing 350Mill rows. I want to add a filter to the existing replication which will remove some burden on report data.

Can i add straight away or do i need to make any changes to the existing replication.?

Could you provide any information on this.

Comment: At the very least, you'll need to re-initialize that specific article, no? Are you asking if there are any *other* changes that need to be made? Also, is the filter horizontal or vertical?

Comment: We already set up replication and now we need to put some filter on to this. If i add filter straight on publisher properties, is this going to break replication..??

Comment: It will be "broken" for that article until such time as you can re-initialize it (since the subscriber, having all of the data now, will be out of sync with what it *should* have). There are ways to minimize the re-init time, but it's just that - minimization, not elimination.